# Tag synonym request [autocompleter] -> [autocomplete]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm suggesting [autocompleter](/questions/tagged/autocompleter) be a synonym of [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete). [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) has 3,385 questions as of posting this, and [autocompleter](/questions/tagged/autocompleter) only has 24.

It doesn't seem like  [autocompleter](/questions/tagged/autocompleter) questions are referring to a particular widget or technology, and [autocompleter](/questions/tagged/autocompleter) does not have a tag wiki, while [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) does.

Comment: [autocompletest]